# Regex Javascript, must start with letters, no spaces in the beggining, accents allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and try to figure out how to check form validation before POSTing it with fetch :

1. Must starts with letters, accents are allowed : A-zÀ-ú
2. Not allowed : one or multiple whitespaces only -> like the field is : '.' or '......' where all points are whitespaces.
3. Dash is allowed (but not as a first char).
4. Whitespaces are allowed but only to separate words

Exemples of inputs in my form (without the quotes) :

**Allowed** :

- "John"
- "John-Rambo"
- "John Rambo"

**Not Allowed** (replace all dots by whitespaces) :

- "John28"
- ".......John Rambo"
- "John Rambo......."
- "."
- "........."

My current regex : `let myRegEx = /(^[A-zÀ-ú]+$)([ \-])/`

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the hyphen and space into your character class. You'll need two character classes, one for the characters that can be the leading character and then one for all characters.

```
^[A-zÀ-ú][A-zÀ-ú -]+$
```

You can add `[A-zÀ-ú]` after the `+` if the string should not be ending in a hyphen or space as well.

I'm not sure what the `([ \-])` was for but that is after the `$` which marks the end of the string so that won't match.

https://regex101.com/r/8E3rhI/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to check all your conditions in only one regex. I think you would need one regex to check the characters and an other to check if there is more than one consecutive space.

**You would need to make sure the name matches this regex:** `/^[A-zÀ-ù][A-zÀ-ú- ]*$/`
**And that it doesn't match this regex:** `/( ){2,}/`

Answer (score 0):

So, since this is javascript, you can actually trim the whitespace fairly easily with [String.trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

After some playing around, I came to this regex:

```regex
(\w+([\s-]|$))+
```

It works OK, and I hope it will fit your needs :)